# SSH automatic logon works for one user but not the other

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I want to enable automatic ssh login using the *.ssh/config* file for my *git* user.

Here is my *.ssh/config* file:

```
Host test
    HostName myserver.net
    User test
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host git
    HostName myserver.net
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It works for my *test* user but not for my *git* user so my global SSH configuration is correct.

The configuration are exactly the same as far as I know. It used to work with *git* user but I'm unable what change has broken the automatic logon.

When I type:

```
ssh -v git
```

I get the following log:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
Offering RSA public key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@myserver.net's password: _
```

Does anyone know what could be a possible difference

Comment: Hows the ssh servers config setup, do you have Authorised keys in each  home directory per user or do you have a global authorised keys file in sshd_config ?

Comment: I have a global configuration, and each user has its own authorized_keys files. But this file is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the log on the *server* to see why it doesn't accept the user's key. You may need to change the log level in `sshd_config` to

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

and restart `sshd`.

Comment: Which file does the log output?

Comment: On Debian it's `/var/log/auth.log`, but the location varies between distributions. Check `/etc/syslog.conf` for the destination of `auth` messages.

Comment: This is indeed /var/log/auth.log and I get the following: Nov 11 12:52:42 myserver sshd[18387]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/git

Comment: I reset /home/git permission to 700 and it worked.